# spring cloud contract messaging - how to define an attribute and assert with a regex

Tags: spring-cloud-contract

**Given**:

a defined contract with Spring Cloud Contract Messaging.
[image]

https://github.com/nusmanov/producer/blob/master/src/test/resources/contracts/user-presence.yaml

Question:

- Is it possible on producer side to mark attributes for regex matching?
- Because per default *spring cloud verifier* generates tests with assertions like:

  - `assert user == joe`
- What i need is (on producer side)

  - `assert user has characters`

**Producer**: https://github.com/nusmanov/producer

**Consumer**: https://github.com/nusmanov/consumer

Comment: by attributes you mean headers?

Comment: ` define an attribute for example a user, which has characters` user or id.

Comment: You haven't answered my question. Do you want to set this value aa a message header?

Comment: i edited my question. Hope it is clear, now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. Please read the documentation here https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-contract/docs/current/reference/html/project-features.html#contract-dsl-dynamic-properties . Example of a messaging contract with matchers can be found here https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-contract/blob/e91b91efba60c52c3e8a6e65171a9f6dd18cb276/spring-cloud-contract-stub-runner/src/test/groovy/org/springframework/cloud/contract/stubrunner/messaging/integration/StubRunnerIntegrationMessageSelectorSpec.groovy#L198-L220 . I'm pasting it for your convenience

```
Contract.make {
    input {
        messageFrom "foo"
        messageHeaders {
            header("foo", $(anyUuid()))
        }
        messageBody(foo: 123)
    }
}
```